# PHP multiple if...elseif statement

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

This is a portion of the code I am working on:

```
if($access == 2)

{

    if ($permre['pages'] == indi_add)// 
        {echo "show page";}

    if ($permre['pages'] == mass_add)// 
        {echo "show page";}

    if ($permre['pages'] == export)// 
        {echo "show page";}

}

elseif ($access == 0)

{

    if ($permre['pages'] == indi_add)// 
        {echo "dont show page";}

    if ($permre['pages'] == mass_add)// 
        {echo "dont show page";}

    if ($permre['pages'] == export)// 
        {echo "dont show page";}**

}
```

I am creating a page where when a condition such as `$access == 2` is executed it has multiple values. Some the values include: indi_add, mass_add and export. Then I want to use these values to create 3 conditions as shown above.

However, when executing this code, only the first if statement is being executed and the rest aren't. Is there a away where I can make php check the 3 if statements at once and do the action requested?

Adding on, I can't use `if(condition1 && condition2 && condition3)` because there is a possibility that one of the conditions may not be satisfied.

So how do I go about executing all the statements even if the first statement if true or false? I am actually getting the values such as indi_add, mass_add and export from phpmyadmin database. The query goes something like this:

> "select pages from access where access = 2".

Due to the query above I get the page values which are the ones mentioned above. The echo page is just an example. In my actual coding, if the statement for `access == 2` if true, the result is that a particular page will be activated. I am trying to do something like access control. Also, behind the scene, access level for each page can be changed by the admin. Therefore, the query above may bring different results every time the access level changes. I'm hoping to find a way where I can execute the if conditions whenever they are true.

Comment: do you use the edited indentation or the previous where the echo statements are commented out?

Comment: srry for being a noob but what do you mean by edited indentation...

Comment: [Replace conditional with Polymorphism](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)

Answer (score 3):

You say "it has multiple values". What has? because this block:

```
if ($permre['pages'] == indi_add)// {echo "show page";}
if ($permre['pages'] == mass_add)// {echo "show page";}
if ($permre['pages'] == export)// {echo "show page";}
```

Will have only 1 hit. The var. `$permre['pages']` can have only one value. A different one each time you run the script, true, but per run it can't have "indi_add" AND "mass_add" at the same time.

Also: wat is `indi_add`. Shouldn't that be `"indi_add"`, if its a string or `$indi_add` if it's a variable?

Comment: indi_add, mass_add and export are the values I will get when I query it from mysql database under the field pages.

Comment: But if they are values (strings?) you want to add `"` to them! Your comparison will be useless otherwise. Also, one var (your `$permre['page']`) can still only have 1 value. So you will trigger 1 of your ifs each time around.

Comment: so which means that there is no way that I will be able to trigger all the values?

Comment: I think you should track back and think about how you want those values to be available in 1 variable. Do you run this piece of code multiple times? then yes, it will work (if you fix that `indi_add` to `"indi_add"` or `$indi_add` !!!!), otherwise, think on how you want 1 thing to be equal to 2 different things? That can only be the case if the `indi_add` and the `mass_add` are the same, which i presume they are not.

Comment: actually..i wanted to do it variable by variable as u suggested tht will mean the code written will be a lot...like abt 2000 lines of code...i dont know whether that will be a suitable way to do it...if there is another way around...

Comment: I still have no real clue to what you are trying to do, but the fact that there are no 2 if's triggering in 1 run is not an error, but expected: you are checking _one and the same_ variable, right? If you are running it multiple times with different values, but your if is not working, it might be because of the missing `"` or `$`. So please, debug those things for yourself, do some echoes to see where it goes wrong....

Answer (score 2):

I would use a switch instead of all the if statments

```
switch ($i) {
    case 0:
        echo "i equals 0";
        break;
    case 1:
        echo "i equals 1";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "i equals 2";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for something like this:

```
switch($access) {
  case 2:
    switch($premre['pages']) {
      case "indi_add":
      case "mass_add":
      case "export":
      echo "show page";
      break;
    }
    break;
  default:
      echo "not show page";
      break;
}
```

If you need something individual to happen for each of the statements just add it to their case, then break it. Same goes with default, if you need something specific to happen just replace it with a similar case as the first one.

Edit: example with adding code to each case by request of OP

```
switch($access) {
  case 2:
    switch($premre['pages']) {
      case "indi_add":
        echo "something happens here when indi_add is run";
        doSomething();  //Runs a function for indi_add
        break;
      case "mass_add":
        echo "something happens here when mass_add is run";
        doSomethingElse();  //Runs another function for indi_add
        break;
      case "export":
        echo "show page for export";
      break;
    }
    break;
  default:
      echo "not show page";
      break;
}
```

Comment: hmm....but the thing is that since im doing a show/hide type for each of the diff value...it wont be an echo. It will actually be different result for every value...therefore, a common echo will not help for me...as if indi_add comes out when access = 2, it will be an url link to a page...same goin for the other 2 values which will be associated with 2 different url links...

Comment: srry was looking at codes...didnt read the msg below the tags...ill try the method then..thank u for replying...:D

Comment: the reason for the echo is because you used that in your example, you can add any code you want to each case, or the same code for multiple cases like I've done in the example. I've also done a default which means all cases where access is something other than 2 will not show the page, but you can add different cases to that too if needed.

Comment: if its not too much trouble..can you give an example for the adding of code to each case....?

Comment: @neelima updated the post with an example of how you can run code for each of the specific cases if access is 2. You can also replace the code in default with similar code to run different code each case there or you can replace default all together with another case (example: case 0)

Comment: then what is the dosomething() function for?

Comment: @neelima it's just a dummyfunction for showing functionality.. you asked me to show you how you could add different functionality to each case, but you didn't really include anything in the OP that hsowed what was going to happen, so I put in some dummyfunctions to show you one possible way to execute something on a specific case. Replace it with whatever it is you want to happen

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstand, but a single variable cannot have multiple values.

It *can*, however, contain multiple values if encoded in some way. In this particular case you're probably looking for bitmasks/flags.

First define the "values", making sure not to overlap bits patterns (unless this allowed in your system of values):

```
define('indi_add', 0x0001);
define('mass_add', 0x0002);
define('export', 0x0004);
```

Now you can combine these into a variable using bitwise OR operator `|`:

```
$permre['pages'] = indi_add | mass_add;
```

Finally, use bitwise AND operator `&` to check if the variable contains one of the flags:

```
if ($permre['pages'] & indi_add)// 
    {echo "show page";}

if ($permre['pages'] & mass_add)// 
    {echo "show page";}

if ($permre['pages'] & export)// 
    {echo "show page";}
```